# Files downloading

Tags: java-me

How do I go about connecting to a server and check if there is a file to be downloaded using Java ME?

Should I use POST method, post all my required data to server and see what the server response back? And also what are the headers do I have to post together with my data?

Or do I have to use a Get method?

Comment: How is the file you want to download served? Over HTTP?

Comment: Yes,it will be over a httpconnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need it to do by hand. Just use

```
HttpConnection connection = Connector.open(url);
DataInputStream stream = connection.openDataInputStream();
while(stream.read() != -1) {
    //your stuff if anything there
}
```